# Leaflet map custom styling

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, styling

I'm trying to add custom styling to a leaflet map.  I have created a json object via openmaptiles.org (http://editor.openmaptiles.org/#3.04/47.32/10.72), downloaded the object and included it in my project wrapping it like

```
const style = [{created object...}]
module.exports = style
```

I'm then importing it into my mapwrapper and using it like this

```
mapStyle = require('../../public/css/map_style')

const MapWrapper = function(element, lat, lng, zoom){
  const osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  const osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl);

  this.map = L.map(element)
  .addLayer(osm)
  .setView([lat, lng], zoom)

  L.geoJSON(mapStyle).addTo(this.map)
};
```

But when the map loads the styling doesn't show and there are no errors.  Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: You can't style OSM raster tiles. See https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/leaflet/ for how to use openmaptiles with Leaflet.